# Selenium WebDriver Testng

Tags: testng

Testng query - Need to run a method before Data provider run and need to run a method after completion of test with completion of all the data from data provider. @After method is running for all the data for the test. Can you please help me.

Now I am able to do with @AfterClass annotation .For this I have to write different test in different class .But I want to write all the test in one class

Comment: Can you provide [concise] code or other examples of what you have written and want to change? This will help people see what you are trying to do and provide specific suggestions to your case.

Answer (score 0):

you can call the other method which you want to run as the first call in the dataprovider method or the perform all the actions which you want to do in either the constructor of the class containing DP or in a static block. For your second query you can use @AfterTest as well or @AfterSuite whatever suits you best